# iOS Development - Executing Code After Leaving a tab in a tabbed application

Tags: ios, swift

I want to execute some code whenever a user leaves one of the tabs in my tabbed application.  What should I do?

Comment: I am not sure why many people have voted that the question is unclear or spam :( I am sorry if it was so, someone understood me and answered my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that tab use a custom subclass of UIViewController. (Or whatever parent class you're using). Implement `viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)`. Put the code you want to execute in that method.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!